# how to set a default http header with alamofire

Tags: alamofire

I want to set a header so that all requests include an authorized token header once the user logs in.  I thought I could set the header in the shared alamofire manager by calling my `setToken` function but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.  What's my mistake?  Is there a better way of setting a default header for all alamofire requests?

```
 class UserService : NSObject {

    static let manager: Alamofire.Manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration:  NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    class func setToken(token:String){
        manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
            "x-token": token
        ]

    }

   class func addFriend(user:LoggedUser, uname:String, callback:((success: Bool, errorMsg: String?)->Void)) {

        let params:[String : AnyObject] = ["uname": uname]

        let url = AppConfig.sharedInstance().baseURL() + "/user/\(user.userId!)/friends"
        Alamofire.request(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)
            .responseJSON(options: .MutableContainers, completionHandler:{ (request, response, JSON, error) -> Void in

        //token is not set in the request
    }

}
```

Comment: For future readers, please note that `Alamofire.Manager` is now `Alamofire.SessionManager`: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#namespace-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never make use of your custom manager, use following code:

```
class CustomManager: Manager {
    static public let manager = CustomManager.generateManager()
    class func generateManager()-> CustomManager {
        var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders ?? [:]
        defaultHeaders["x-token""] = "token"
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders
        let manager = CustomManager(configuration: configuration)
        return manager
    }
}

class UserService : NSObject {

   class func addFriend(user:LoggedUser, uname:String, callback:((success: Bool, errorMsg: String?)->Void)) {

        let params:[String : AnyObject] = ["uname": uname]

        let url = AppConfig.sharedInstance().baseURL() + "/user/\(user.userId!)/friends"
        CustomManager.manager(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)
            .responseJSON(options: .MutableContainers, completionHandler:{ (request, response, JSON, error) -> Void in

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the end of your code, it's not even closing brackets properly

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake was using the class function rather than the shared instance when I made the request.

So it should be

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)
```

rather than

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)
```

Comment: I'm sure that `Alamofire.request(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)`
makes use of `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.POST, url , parameters:params, encoding:.JSON)`

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a custom `SessionManager` in Alamofire 4, now in Alamofire 5 it's called `Session` and you can create it this way:

```
 let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
 var defaultHeaders = HTTPHeaders.default
 defaultHeaders["X-API-Version"] = "1.0"
 configuration.headers = defaultHeaders
 let yourManager = Alamofire.Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Base on the doc its not recommended to set headers on `Session`
---- Excerpt

URLSessionConfiguration is not the recommended location to set Authorization or Content-Type headers. Instead, add them to Requests using the provided headers APIs, using ParameterEncoders, or a RequestAdapter.

Source: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#creating-custom-session-instances

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that conforms to protocol RequestAdapter. You will have to implement this function `func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {`. Inside it do:

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    var urlRequest = urlRequest
    urlRequest.setValue("YourUserAgent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    return urlRequest
}
```

In this function you can add whatever headers you want.

And then do:

`sessionManager.adapter = "Class that conforms to RequestAdapter"`, where sessionManager is your Alamofire SessionManager.